# wp_query get attachments in larger size

Tags: wp-query, attachments

I'm using wp_query to get all attachments, and it works, but I wonder how could I get attachments in full size because this query returns images in medium.

```
<?php 
    $args = array('post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <?php
                the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' );
                the_content();
            ?>
        </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the raw post data...

```
while (have_posts() ) { 
  the_post(); ?>
  <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>><?php
      var_dump($post); ?>
  </article><?php 
}
```

You will see that there is nothing in there to specify "medium", so I went looking. [There is a filter on `the_content`...](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L136)

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_attachment' );
```

... that [juggles data for "attachment" post types](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L1576).

```
1576    function prepend_attachment($content) {
1577            $post = get_post();
1578    
1579            if ( empty($post->post_type) || $post->post_type != 'attachment' )
1580                    return $content;
1581    
1582            if ( wp_attachment_is( 'video', $post ) ) {
1583                    $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( get_the_ID() );
1584                    $atts = array( 'src' => wp_get_attachment_url() );
1585                    if ( ! empty( $meta['width'] ) && ! empty( $meta['height'] ) ) {
1586                            $atts['width'] = (int) $meta['width'];
1587                            $atts['height'] = (int) $meta['height'];
1588                    }
1589                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
1590                            $atts['poster'] = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
1591                    }
1592                    $p = wp_video_shortcode( $atts );
1593            } elseif ( wp_attachment_is( 'audio', $post ) ) {
1594                    $p = wp_audio_shortcode( array( 'src' => wp_get_attachment_url() ) );
1595            } else {
1596                    $p = '<p class="attachment">';
1597                    // show the medium sized image representation of the attachment if available, and link to the raw file
1598                    $p .= wp_get_attachment_link(0, 'medium', false);
1599                    $p .= '</p>';
1600            }
1601    
1602            /**
1603             * Filter the attachment markup to be prepended to the post content.
1604             *
1605             * @since 2.0.0
1606             *
1607             * @see prepend_attachment()
1608             *
1609             * @param string $p The attachment HTML output.
1610             */
1611            $p = apply_filters( 'prepend_attachment', $p );
1612    
1613            return "$p\n$content";
1614    }
```

The relevant lines are 1597 and 1598. [`wp_get_attachment_link()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L1532), which in turn uses [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/media.php#L727) (line 1545), which uses [`image_downsize()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/media.php#L150)... and there is a promising filter:

```
167         if ( $out = apply_filters( 'image_downsize', false, $id, $size ) ) {
168                 return $out;
169         }
```

*Et viola!*

```
function image_size_hack() {
  $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url();
  $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata();
  $width= $height = '';
  if (!empty($meta['width'])) {
    $width = $meta['width'];
  }
  if (!empty($meta['height'])) {
    $width = $meta['height'];
  }
  return array( $img_url, $width, $height, false );
}
add_filter( 'image_downsize',  'image_size_hack');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the wp_get_attachment_image function as per your need.
pass the image size you want to display.

```
wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
```

more info at:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image

Comment: This is the correct answer, just echo the wp_get_attachment_image at any size you want

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set your own image tag. You can replace the_content(); with this.

```
<img src="<?= wp_get_attachment_url(get_the_ID()); ?>"/>
```